# jQuery problem with multiple radio selects

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to validate a form that contains several different radio buttons. A few radio buttons in the form have the same classname 'video_type'.

In the jQuery validation script, after the form is submitted I want to check if any of the radio buttons with the classname 'video_type' have been selected. If the user has selected **at least one** radio button with the classname 'video_type' and the value as 1, it should return true. Otherwise it should return false.

At the moment I'm using this:

**HTML:**

```
<input type="radio" name="video_option_1" class="video_option" value="1">Yes
<input type="radio" name="video_option_1" class="video_option" value="0">No

<input type="radio" name="video_option_2" class="video_option" value="1">Yes
<input type="radio" name="video_option_2" class="video_option" value="0">No
```

**jQuery:**

```
$("#completeOrderForm").submit(function(){
 if($(".video_type").val() == 0){
   $("#showerrors").show().html("Please select a video type.");
   return false;
 } 
});
```

But I realise it's incorrect. What do I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
if ($(".video_option[value='1']:checked").length == 0) {
   $("#showerrors").show().html("Please select a video type.");
   return false;
 }
```

Basically you're selecting every element with the class `.video_option` that have the value 1 (`[value='1']`) and are checked (using the [`:checked`](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) selector). It then counts the amount of elements selected, if the result is `0` no radio's are checked.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bjorn/UwufF/6/

**EDIT**
You talk about radio buttons with the classname `video_type` yet the code shows `video_option`, I went by the code when making the example.

Comment: Updated example, missed the requirement about the value being 1.

Comment: Yeah, sorry - I forgot to change the name attribute from my code. Your solution works perfectly. Thanks!